# java equals String - New to Java and Programming

Tags: java, equals

```
public class ZooTiere {
    String name;
    int beine;
    String fliegt;
    String federn;
    String gefahr;

    public ZooTiere(String name, int beine, String fliegt, String federn, String gefahr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.beine = beine;
        this.fliegt = fliegt;
        this.federn = federn;
        this.gefahr = gefahr;
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZooTiere Alligator = new ZooTiere("Alligator",4, "ja", "ja", "ja");
        ZooTiere Papagei = new ZooTiere("Papagei",2, "ja", "ja", "nein");
        ZooTiere[] tiere = {Alligator, Papagei};

        for (int i = 0; i < tiere.length; i++) {
            if (args.equals(tiere[i].name)) {
                System.out.println(tiere[i].beine);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Im really new to this and I try to figure out why I can't compare the args with the String in tiere[i].name. How could I do this? First I tried to compare the args with the name of the ZooTiere Object like Alligator etc.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why did you use `tiere[i]`?

Comment: Note that `args` is also an array.

Comment: I used tiere[i] to get the animal "tier" currently active in the for loop and compare its name to a String

Yes, the array was the problem. But what would I do if I want to call the main method always with just one argument "The animal name". 

if (args[0].equals(tiere[i].name))?

Comment: args is an array, you need to pick one, say, arg[0] if only supplied one argument

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper points out, `args` is an array - you need to compare an element in the array, rather than the array itself:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZooTiere Alligator = new ZooTiere("Alligator",4, "ja", "ja", "ja");
        ZooTiere Papagei = new ZooTiere("Papagei",2, "ja", "ja", "nein");
        ZooTiere[] tiere = {Alligator, Papagei};

        for (int i = 0; i < tiere.length; i++) {
            if (args[0].equals(tiere[i].name)) {
                System.out.println(tiere[i].beine);

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. As mentioned the problem was, that I didn't see that args [] is an array. I solved it with a for loop over the args.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < tiere.length; j++) {
            if (args[0].equals(tiere[j].name)) {
```